# how can i make this .htaccess handle https as well. it is now wel on http

Tags: apache, .htaccess, lamp

how can i make this inherited  code to handle https requests as well. i believe a minimum adjustment can do it but my limited .htacess prevents me to

```html
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /



RewriteRule ^tags-(.*)/ tags.php?keyword=$1
RewriteRule ^tags-(.*) tags.php?keyword=$1
RewriteRule ^profile-(.*)/ profile.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^profile-(.*) profile.php?username=$1

RewriteRule ^jobagency-([^/]+)/?$ agency.php?channel=$1   [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^jobagency-([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ agency.php?channel=$1&page=$2

RewriteRule ^jobagency-([^/]+)/search/?$ agency.php?channel=$1&search=search   [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^jobagency-([^/]+)/search/([0-9]+)/?$ agency.php?channel=$1&page=$2&search=search


RewriteRule ^jobagency-([^/]+)/category/?$ agency.php?channel=$1&category=   [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^jobagency-([^/]+)/category/([^/]+)/?$ agency.php?channel=$1&category=$2


RewriteRule ^agency-(.*)/ index.php?channel=$1
RewriteRule ^agency-(.*) index.php?channel=$1

RewriteRule ^category-(.*)/ category.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^category-(.*) category.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(\d+)-(.*)-([^-]+)\.html jobs.php?id=$3&fbpageid=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

But the code you attached does not has to do with the protocol at all. Should work with http and https as well.

Comment: Klezper  it does not work. goes well with http, if i add https it goes url was not found on this server.

Comment: i found out it does not work because of ? encoded to 3f .  Still looking for solution if anyone has clue how to fix this.